# Tool to monitor client side performance and generate sophisticated reports about performance

Tags: performance, client-server, performance-testing

I am having an application developed in angular 1.x series. It is consuming RESTful services developed in Microsoft.Net. These RESTful services are consumed by other applications and they are working seamlessly for other clients. End user is complaining about performance issues. Since Service side is already optimized I would like to focus on client side performance first.
Currently we are using chrome dev tools and profiling tools for finding performance issues. Is there any sophisticated tool (open source or proprietary but preferably open source) which will monitor the application and generate the detailed report which will help to investigate the problem?

**Note** - One of the tool which I know is HP loadrunner. Are there any other alternatives?

Comment: Tell us more about the client side application set you are trying to investigate.   Is it a thick client where you need to profile the client?  What are the tools used to build the client? .Net? Java? Python? C? COBOL? Clarion?  You need to understand how the poorly performing client is built in order to understand how to peak under the covers.

Comment: It is browser based application developed in Angular 1.x series 
Server side is RESTful services developed using Microsoft.Net. It is mentioned in the question.

Comment: Why would your developers not take advantage of the profiling tools available inside of Visual Studio?  Similarly for the client, why would they not take advantage of the client profiling tools built into the developer tools section of every browser?

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious choice is [YSlow](http://yslow.org/), the main features include:

- Grades web page based on one of three predefined ruleset or a user-defined ruleset;
- It offers suggestions for improving the page's performance;
- Summarizes the page's components;
- Displays statistics about the page;
- Provides tools for performance analysis, including Smush.it™ and JSLint.

---

If you need to generate the load (represent hundreds of concurrent application users) while measuring client-side performance you can take a look at the following free and open source solutions:

- [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)
- [The Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/)
- [Gatling](http://gatling.io/)
- [Tsung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/)
- [Locust](http://locust.io/)

Check out [How to Choose the Best Open Source Load Testing Tool (Infographic)](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/choose-best-open-source-load-testing-tool-infographic) for main features highlighted and compared.